# Using previous row values when creating new R dataframe variable

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, group-by, lag

I'd really appreciate some help with an issue I have with my R dataframe. Couldn't find a similar thread, so please share if it exists already!

I have the following data:

```
mydata <- data.frame(inflow=c(50,60,55,70,80),
                     outflow=c(70,80,70,65,65),
                     current=c(100,100,100,100,100))
```

I want to create a new column which does something like:

`mutate(calc=pmax(lag(calc,default=current)+inflow-outflow,inflow))`

which basically creates a new column called calc that chooses between the maximum of a) the previous row value of calc plus this row's inflow minus outflow or b) this row's inflow value. pmax is a function from a package called rmpfr which selects the maximum across given columns per row.

so my results will be: row1 = max(100+50-70, 50) which is 80, row2 = max(80+60-80,60) which is 60 and so on.

The main issue is that the lag function doesn't allow for taking previous row values for the same column you're creating, it has to be a column that already exists in the data. I thought of doing it in steps by creating the calc column first and then adding a second calculation step, but can't exactly work it out.

Lastly, I know that using a for loop might be a solution but was wondering if there is a different way? my data is grouped by an extra column and not sure the for loop will work well with grouped data rows?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: check `cummax` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
# I don't define the current column, as this is handled with the .init argument of accumulate2
mydata <- data.frame(
  inflow=c(50,60,55,70,80),
  outflow=c(70,80,70,65,65)
)

# define your recursive function
flow_function <- function(current, inflow, outflow){
  pmax(inflow, inflow - outflow + current)
}

mydata %>%
  mutate(result = accumulate2(inflow, outflow, flow_function, .init = 100)[-1] %>% unlist)

#   inflow outflow result
# 1     50      70     80
# 2     60      80     60
# 3     55      70     55
# 4     70      65     70
# 5     80      65     85
```

---

**Detail**

The [`purrr::accumulate`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/accumulate.html) family of functions are designed to perform recursive calculations.

`accumulate` can handle functions which take the previous value plus values from one other column, whilst `accumulate2` allows for a second additional column. Your scenario falls into the later.

`accumulate2` expects the following arguments:

- `.x` - the first column for the calculation.
- `.y` - the second column for the calculation.
- `.f` - the function to apply recursively: this should have three arguments, the first of which is the recursive argument.
- `.init` - (optional) the initial value to use as the first argument.

So in your case the function to pass to `.f` will be

```r
# define your recursive function
flow_function <- function(current, inflow, outflow){
  pmax(inflow, inflow - outflow + current)
}
```

We first test what this produces outside of a `dplyr::mutate`

```
# note I don't define the current column, as this is handled with the .init argument
mydata <- data.frame(
  inflow=c(50,60,55,70,80),
  outflow=c(70,80,70,65,65)
)


purrr::accumulate2(mydata$inflow, mydata$outflow, flow_function, .init = 100)
# returns
# [[1]]
# [1] 100
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 80
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 60
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 55
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] 70
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] 85
```

So there's two things to note about the returned value:

- The returned object is a list, so we'll want to `unlist` back to a vector.
- The list has 6 entries as it includes the initial value, we'll want to drop this.

These two final steps are brought together in the full example at the top.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the cummax function will help

```
mutate(calc=pmax(cummax(current+inflow-outflow),inflow))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried that but doesn't help with my case. results in the following values: 80,80,85,105,115 while I need: 80,60,55,70,85. I think cummax treats each row of current+inflow-outflow independent of previous rows, while I need something to capture the calculated column calc from just the previous row, after each calculation step. Something very easy to do in Excel but apparently not in R !

Comment: I see. I tried to correct, but noticed a problem. Could you explain why the first value of calc should be 80? If I understand correctly, it should be pmax(previous current + inflow - outflow; inflow), but there is no previous calc value, as it is the first entry.

Comment: i think the correct calculation for the new calc column is pmax( previous row of same column calc but for first row it uses the current=100 +inflow -outflow, inflow). so the first row is max of (100+50-70) or 50, which is 80. 2nd row is max (80 (last row of calc) +60-80, 60) which is 60 and so on... seems to me like a for loop is a solution but wondering if there is a cleaner single mutate line for this type of problem. thanks